# I am trying to run vs code debugger for my backend on nodejs but it's not getting triggered

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I have added this configuration:

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Launch Chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "type": "chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },  
]
```

But it's just not launching at all. I want to see response in my vscode editor itself.

Comment: it looks like you are trying to run a nodejs app with configuration where type is "chrome", try specifying "node" instead

Comment: @Ruslan ok i will try to do that